# Can g++ (gcc) 11 be used on Debian Bullseye?

Tags: c++, gcc, debian, clang, c++20

Can g++ (gcc) 11.1 be used on Debian Bullseye?

Debian 11 (bullseye) is soon to be released, and I am interested in a compiler with C++20 and modules support.

Debian 11 currently has gcc 10.2 and clang 11. clang 11 has some C++20 support.

Is Debian more conservative with gcc as opposed to clang because the OS uses gcc?

Comment: The Debian 11 Hard Freeze was on [2021-03-12](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianBullseye), which happens to be in between the release of [clang-11](https://releases.llvm.org/) and [gcc-11](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html), so it could very well be a simple matter of timing.

Comment: You can probably build the compiler from the source if there was no other choice.

Comment: @Frank Thank You. Possibly, but at the time of this question, Debian 11 was in Full Freeze (as of 07-17-21).

Comment: @Coder I'm not sure I follow. What matters is that Debian 11 was not frozen when clang-11 was released, but was when gcc-11 was, which seems to me like a plausible explanation for the discrepency.

Comment: @Frank Re: "not sure I follow". When you said "matter of timing", I interpreted it to mean that you thought that maybe Debian would add gcc-11 to Debian 11 and so I was wondering about that given the Full Freeze now. However, I now see what you meant, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Coder no sweat, I can see how my comment could be interpreted that way.

Answer (score 5):

Since the links in the next paragraph are obsolete because Ubuntu 19.04 has reached its end of life, I refer readers of this answer to the more general case which is applicable for all users of gcc in Debian-based operating systems. For more information on installing non-standard versions of gcc and g++ in Debian-based operating systems please refer to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446899/).

---

Here it is, [g++-11](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/amd64/g++-11/download) from the default Ubuntu repositories ready to install in Debian Bullseye and the package's dependencies are listed on [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/g++-11).

Open the terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Desktop/
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gcc-11/g++-11_11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04_amd64.deb
apt install --simulate ./g++-11_11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04_amd64.deb
```

The last command will return a list of missing dependencies <s>which can be found at [this webpage](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/g++-11)</s>. After all the missing dependency packages have been manually downloaded and installed, the command to install the g++-11 package is as follows:

```
sudo apt install ./g++-11_11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04_amd64.deb
```

The `apt install --simulate` commands will certainly generate unmet dependencies errors at first because the Debian Bullseye default repositories do not contain the gcc-11 dependency package (gcc-10 is the latest version), but they will show a list of missing dependency packages. If you work at it iteratively you will be able to get all of these missing dependency packages installed, so that in the end `sudo apt install ./g++-11_11.1.0-1ubuntu1~21.04_amd64.deb` will run without errors.

Comment: There are no arm64 packages in `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/...`, how come? I thought ARM64 is mainstream enough by now. Trying to get a recent version GCC onto Raspberry Pi...

Comment: Maybe the ARM64 package still has bugs with some models of ARM processors.

Answer (score 3):

**g++-11**, gcc-11 installs OK into 'Debian 11 Bullseye'.

g++-11 and dependencies ...

```
cpp-11_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
g++-11_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
gcc-11_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
gcc-11-base_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libasan6_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libatomic1_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libcc1-0_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libgcc-11-dev_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libgcc-s1_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libgomp1_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libitm1_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
liblsan0_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libquadmath0_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libstdc++-11-dev_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libstdc++6_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libtsan0_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
libubsan1_11.1.0-4_amd64.deb
```

g++-11 https://packages.debian.org/experimental/g++-11

Install : `cd Downloads/` ; `# apt install ./*`

Comment: OK. Thanks much. Do you think that this would be more "stable/reliable" than other packages from "experimental" given that gcc-11 itself is an official "stable" release?

Comment: This gcc-11 build has been tested for a while in Ubuntu, and furthermore a gcc release is usually stable. gcc-11 versus other experimental : gcc-11 is an exception as it depends on a much earlier glibc (libc6) version. Do not expect that with other "expertmental" packages.

Comment: spot on, its moved to testing now https://packages.debian.org/testing/g++-11

Answer (score 2):

That matters with your "`Source.list`".

if your "source.list" is the "Debian 11: Official sources.list":

(`Debian 11` source with `g++(gcc)10`)

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye-updates main contrib
```

then "`apt-cache madison gcc`":

```
gcc | 4:10.2.1-1 | http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages

gcc-defaults |      1.190 | http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main Sources
```

If your "Source.list" is just like:

(`Debian 11` source with `g++(gcc)11`)

```
deb http://mirrors.xmission.com/debian/ testing main non-free contrib

deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
```

then "`apt-cache madison gcc`":

```
gcc | 4:11.2.0-2 | http://mirrors.xmission.com/debian testing/main amd64 Packages

gcc | 4:11.2.0-2 | http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages

gcc | 4:11.2.0-2 | http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
```

So, if you want to change your `Debian 11`'s `GCC` from `10` to `11`,

you could change that to your `Debian` "source.list".

Just do this below:

```
cd /etc/apt/ && sudo nano sources.list
```

And then change `"source.list"` with adding that source which can help you download the `g++(gcc)11`. please use the below to replace your Debian source or that offical sources:

```
deb http://mirrors.xmission.com/debian/ testing main non-free contrib
deb http://http.us.debian.org/debian testing main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Looks like an incomplete answer. I'm unable to understand this answer. What changes does one need to make in `sources.list` in order to install `g++11`?

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks for reminding me! Sorry, maybe I didn't make it clear. Debian's official source supports `GCC10`. The official source does not currently support `GCC11`. So if `GCC11` is needed, we need to look for other Debian sources. I have now supplemented my answer. Did I make it clear this time? Thanks!

Comment: @VittoreMarcas With this, I can use GCC 12 on Debian Bullseye. Thank you.

Comment: @anta40 It makes me very happy to be able to help you. Also, thank you for your feedback!

Comment: @VittoreMarcas: I've not tried this, but I guess it should work (or at least I got some ideas as to what I should be trying). Thanks for updating your answer. Upvoted.

Comment: Where is the `source.list` file? Also is this the fastest way these days - I'm tempted to look into using `homebrew` for this.

Comment: @JarrodSmith the file `source.list` was under the `/etc/apt/sources.list` on Debian.

Comment: This is not a reliable solution, it will update a LOT of your stable packages to TESTING packages. DO NOT use this method.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need `bookworm (testing)` to install this package.
See here:

https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye&keywords=gcc-11

Answer (score -1):

For reference, here's the debs list for **gcc-12 on Debian 11**.

(extracted from DockerFile, just run the commands in a terminal one at a time):

```
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/g++-12_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/cpp-12_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12-base_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/gcc-12_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libgcc-12-dev_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++-12-dev_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libasan8_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libtsan2_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libcc1-0_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libitm1_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libatomic1_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/liblsan0_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libubsan1_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libquadmath0_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libgcc-s1_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libgomp1_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-12/libstdc++6_12.2.0-14_amd64.deb

RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6_2.36-9_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc6-dev_2.36-9_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-dev-bin_2.36-9_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./locales ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/locales-all_2.36-9_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./locales ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-l10n_2.36-9_all.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/libc-bin_2.36-9_amd64.deb

RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-common_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/libbinutils_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf-nobfd0_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/libctf0_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/b/binutils/libgprofng0_2.40.50.20230611-2_amd64.deb

RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libz/libzstd/libzstd1_1.5.4+dfsg2-5_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/j/jansson/libjansson4_2.14-2_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gmp/libgmp10_6.2.1+dfsg1-1.1_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/rpcsvc-proto/rpcsvc-proto_1.4.3-1_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/i/isl/libisl23_0.23-1_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mpclib3/libmpc3_1.1.0-1_amd64.deb
RUN wget -q -P ./deb ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mpfr4/libmpfr6_4.0.2-1_amd64.deb

RUN apt-get purge -y locales
RUN apt install --simulate ./deb/*.deb
RUN cd locales && dpkg --auto-deconfigure -R --install .
RUN cd deb && dpkg --auto-deconfigure -R --install . || apt install -y locales
RUN dpkg --configure -a
```